# inheriting interfaces and COM-interop best practices?

Tags: c#, com-interop

I have a question that is not a direct coding problem, so I am not sure this is the place to ask. If not please advise on where better to ask.

I have a .Net assembly exposed to COM. It uses a base class and several derived classes, all exposed via interfaces.

Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseFoo : IBaseFoo
{
    public abstract int X { get; }
    public abstract int Y { get; }
}
```

with interface:

```
public interface IBaseFoo
{
    int X { get; }
    int Y { get; }
}
```

Derived classes are COM-visible and add additional functionality.

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("123-456-789")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IFooA))]
public class FooA : BaseFoo, IFooA
{
    public override int X { get; }
    public override int Y { get; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

The interface is exposed to COM:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("321-654-987")]
public interface IFooA : IBaseFoo
{
string Z { get; set; }
}
```

At this point, people who have worked with COM will notice a problem. `IFooA` will be exposed to COM, but it will not expose anything from `IBaseFoo`, because inherited interfaces do not make it to COM.

To overcome that, I did this:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("321-654-987")]
public interface IFooA : IBaseFoo
{
    new int X { get; }
    new int Y { get; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

Which finally brings me to my question: I do not like that `new` in there. It feels wrong overriding the inherited interface. Would it be better to create a separate interface `IComFooA`, have `FooA` inherit from it, and expose that interface to COM, the clean up `IFooA` so as to be just .Net? In essence: would you advise the setup sketched above or the one sketched below, and why?

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("123-456-789")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IComFooA))]
public class FooA : BaseFoo, IFooA, IComFooA
{
    public override int X { get; }
    public override int Y { get; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

with `IComFooA` being:

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[Guid("321-654-987")]
public interface IComFooA
{
    int X { get; }
    int Y { get; }
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

And `IFooA` being just:

```
public interface IFooA : IBaseFoo
{
    public string Z { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am a little surprised there are no responses to this. Both suggested ways have many issues. Surely there are opinions on this? The first example just flattens away the inherited interfaces, the second introduces multiple interfaces to the same thing. I am leaning towards the second solution, but I would really appreciate some advice from professionals.

Comment: The notion of "inheriting interfaces" is not a good mental model, it is an illusion brought about by C# syntax.  The coclass does in fact implement both interfaces, the client code must use QueryInterface() to obtain the non-default interface IBaseFoo.  Maybe you did this, it isn't obvious and not always possible.  Scripting languages and old VB versions don't support that for example.  One fatal flaw, IBaseFoo is missing [ComVisible(true)].

Comment: I personally use the C# derivates with new keyword. It's the only to have C# derivation working with COM interfaces.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. My intention is indeed to expose the interfaces to older VB versions and scripting languages, simply said they just have to be able to call my assembly.

Comment: Then it is simple, you must use only one interface.